# Отловить подключение USB-клавиатуры

Tags: linux, usb

Linux. Есть программа (скрипт), которая постоянно висит и тыкается в клавиатуру время от времени, используя `xinput`. Изначально ID клавиатуры программа получала вручную, потом стал автоматически искать нужное в выводе `xinput` по заданной строке (например, `"SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard"`). Всё прекрасно работало до тех пор, пока не понадобилось подключить клавиатуру через KVM. В результате клавиатура при переключении то отключается, то подключается снова, как результат - теряется ID.

Вроде бы не вопрос, сделал правило для `udev`, по которому при подключении клавиатуры программа пинается и ищет её снова. Но тут возникла первая проблема: почему-то правило на `ACTION=="add"` (да и `"remove"` тоже) срабатывает много раз подряд, вот пример лога с одного переключения, с наносекундами:

```
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.706646142] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.741458338] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.743809711] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.746796922] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.755381196] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.755918337] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.756454043] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.763367644] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.765260538] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.766500092] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.769976530] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.770717800] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.777717611] add
[2017-03-28 00:55:02.788441617] add
```

И что с этим делать не совсем понятно.

Но настоящая проблема всё-таки номер два: можно ли обойтись без правил вообще? В идеале скрипт должен быть автономным и не требовать никаких дополнительных действий, отлавливать подключение клавиатуры самостоятельно. Это реально? Если всё-таки нет, то как побороть многократное срабатывание правила?

---

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", \
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c4f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", \
    RUN+="/opt/bin/kvm-kb add k:%k n:%n p:%p"
```

Comment: Покажите ваше правило для udev - без него получается гадание на кофейной гуще. А отловить подключение без редактирования системных конфигов можно попробовать через d-bus.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вместо udev можно попытаться использовать inotify. Взял готовый пример и в нём исправил только путь к папке, в которой создаются USB устройства:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
  int length, i = 0;
  int fd;
  int wd;
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];

  fd = inotify_init();

  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init" );
  }

  wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/dev/bus/usb/002", 
                         IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE );
  length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

  if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror( "read" );
  }  

  while ( i < length ) {
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
    if ( event->len ) {
      if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was created.\n", event->name );       
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was created.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
      else if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was deleted.\n", event->name );       
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was deleted.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
      else if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "The directory %s was modified.\n", event->name );
        }
        else {
          printf( "The file %s was modified.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }

  ( void ) inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
  ( void ) close( fd );

  exit( 0 );
}
```

Подключение флэшки ловит 100%, а вот с отключением - какие-то непонятки...

Comment: О, [Linux::Inotify2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Inotify2) работает (всё на перле, но это не принципиально). Нормально ловит и создание, и удаление, по одному разу.

Comment: Осталось понять как сопоставить `xinput` и каталог :) `lsusb` выдаёт: `Bus 001 Device 029: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory`, a `xinput` видит как `SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard  id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSYSTEM=input` лучше использовать вместо `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` потому что правило с SUBSYSTEM**S** будет отрабатывать на каждом элементе в составе устройства: usb шина, event`ы на клавиатуру и на лампочки.

По сканированию. Лучше смотреть в папку по подключению к порту `/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd` или по модели оборудования    `/dev/input/by-id/usb-A4TECH_USB_Device-event-kbd`